# Mocking static get gorm method in Grails unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I'm using Grails 2.3.7.  I have a simple Person domain object:

```
class Person {
  String name
  static constraints = {}
}
```

And controller:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class PersonController {
  def index() {
    render view:'index', model:[personList:Person.list()]
  }

  def show(Long id) {
    def person = Person.get(id)
    render view:'show', model:[person:person]
  }
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for the controller to exercise the `show` method, but I am not sure how I need to configure the test to ensure that the static call `Person.get(id)` returns a value.

Here's my (failing) attempt:

```
import grails.test.mixin.*
import spock.lang.*

@TestFor(PersonController)
@Mock(Person)
class PersonControllerSpec extends Specification {

  void "Test show action loads Person by id and includes that person in the model rendered"() {
    setup:
      def personMockControl = mockFor(Person)
      personMockControl.demand.static.get() { int id -> new Person(name:"John") }

    when:"A valid person id passed to the show action"
      controller.show(123)

    then:"A model is populated containing the person domain instance loaded by that unique id"
      model.person != null
      model.person.name == "John"
  }
}
```

This test fails because the condition `model.person != null` fails.  How do I rewrite this test in order to make it pass?

EDIT

In this case I can side-step the static method call by reworking the test thusly:

```
void "Test show action loads Person by id and includes that person in the model rendered"() {
  setup:
    def p = new Person(name:"John").save()

  when:"A valid person id passed to the show action"
    controller.show(p.id)

  then:"A model is populated containing the person domain instance loaded by that unique id"
    model.person != null
    model.person.id == p.id
    model.person.name == "John"
}
```

However, I'd really like to understand how to correctly mock the `Person`'s static `get` method.

EDIT 2

Here's another situation to demonstrate my perceived need to mock the `get` method.  Given this filter code:

```
def fitlers = {
  buyFilter(controller:"paypal", action:"buy") {
    after = {
      new VendorPayment(payment:request.payment, vendor: Vendor.get(params.buyerId)).save()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to test that this filter works as expected using the following test:

```
void "test the buyFilter to ensure it creates a VendorPayment when the PayPal plugin controller is called" () {
  setup:
  // how do I mock the Vendor.get(params.buyerId)
  // to return a vendor in order to save a new VendorPayment

  when:
  withFilters(action:"buy") {
    controller.buy()
  }

  then:
  VendorPayment.count() == 1
}
```

Comment: Why is it required to mock `get` method? You are already mocking `Person` in the test and creating a mocked Person instance. Let GORM do its work in picking up the required Person instance inside `show`? Helps?

Comment: I tried to cook up a simple example of needing to mock the `get` method and perhaps that example was too simplistic.  I'll edit the question to add a more involved situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like dmahaptro mentioned, you do not *need* to mock your person.  The preferred/proper way of grabbing an object in a test via `.get()` is the way you have it--you create the domain instance, and pass its id to the controller action for consumption.

However, if you need to mock a static method like this there are two approaches:

1) Use the `mockFor` method provided by `GrailsUnitTestMixin` and then specify the static method like so:

```
GrailsMock mockPerson = mockFor(Person)
mockPerson.demand.static.get() { Long id -> new Person(name:"John") }
```

Note that in your case, the mock's static `get` method did not contain the correct parameter type (`int` was used instead of `Long`) so this method was not being invoked.

2) Modify the class' `metaClass`.  Changing the metaClass is highly discouraged (especially when the `@Mock` annotation already sets everything up for you), and can lead to test leakage (i.e., other tests will not work properly after you've changed the metaClass, unless you restore the original metaclass after the test is done).

That said, for the sake of familiarity, the way you would mock the `.get()` method is via:

`Person.metaClass.static.get = { Long id -> return personWithId }`

Again, this is considered bad practice and should be avoided, but there you have it.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and especially the guidance on the "best practices" concerning grails testing.  I will make sure to avoid having to rely on mocking this type of static method, however, using the following in the setup block still results in a failing test (model.person is null):
`Person.metaClass.static.get = { id -> new Person(name:"John") }` 
This also fails:
 `Person.metaClass.static.get = { id -> new Person(name:"John").save() }`
Why is this still failing in this case?

Comment: @Brice How does it fail?  I've added a type to the `id` param, that may help.

Comment: Yes!  The lack of type on the parameter was killing me!  So now this works and additionally this works as well: `mockFor(Person).demand.static.get() {Long id -> new Person(name:"John")}`

Comment: @Brice Cool, glad to help.  Yeah that's a change in Grails 2 (I believe) -- the type has to match exactly when changing the metaClass.